# How to do insert data every minute into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, logging, c#-4.0

I have to write a data logger application. I want it to insert data into the database every minute (seconds time must be zero). how can I do this? Can I use delegates for inserting? If yes how can I do this?

Comment: What data do you want to insert and where is it coming from?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) to execute recurring events at regular intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of the `DateTime.Now.Minute` and `DateTime.Now.Second` to get the value of the current time.

Handle the [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) class [Elapsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx) event to execute your code in an interval basis.